# Converting image of a histogram into histogram values?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, histogram

So, for a little project I want to do, I want to analyze the distribution of certain parameters. I have images of these distributions, but the data to generate those histograms is not publicly available.

This got me wondering if there is a way of 1/ loading the image of the histogram and 2/ extract the histogram values from this, in Python.

I imagine an answer to this question might fall into any one of the following categories:
1/ There's a package that does this, use it!
2/ It's doable, here are some pointers on how to get started.
3/ You're an idiot for attempting this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somewhere between 2 and 3, it would be relatively straight forward to get relative histogram values just by counting pixels in each bar, it really depends on how much information you can give your system, is the number of bins fixed ? Will you provide the value range? etc... It's probably not worth the effort to code something if the images are drastically varied as you will need a lot of meta data (or your program will be very complex - realms of machine vision). Good luck!

Comment: as I know there is no special module for this - you may only read it with `cv2` or `PIL/pillow` and count pixels in image.

Comment: If your histograms are all in identical layout at same position on page with the same ranges, then it!s not too hard...